# Returning values from function in python 3.5

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I am aware that this question was asked before and I have checked the answers, tried the solutions but so far I couldn't achieve what I want.

Essentially I defined 2 different functions which print values from different sources. What I am trying to do is grab those values and compare them with each other.

```
coins_list_text_file= open("coins.text","r").read().split("\n")
coins_list_text_file = list(filter(None, coins_list_text_file))

def wazi():
    symbol = list(map(lambda x: "{}{}".format(x, "inr").lower(), coins_list_text_file))
    response = requests.get('https://api.wazirx.com/sapi/v1/tickers/24hr')
    wazirx_list = json.loads(response.content)
    filtered_list = [d for d in wazirx_list if d["symbol"] in symbol]
    for values in filtered_list:
        w_symbol = str(values["symbol"])
        w_bid_price = float(values["bidPrice"])
        w_ask_price = float(values["askPrice"])

def binance(): #check prices on binance exchange
    symbol = list(map(lambda x: "{}{}".format(x, "USDT"), coins_list_text_file))
    response = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr')
    binance_list = json.loads(response.content)
    filtered_list = [d for d in binance_list if d["symbol"] in symbol] #filter binance list
    for values in filtered_list:
        binance_symbol = str(values["symbol"])
        binance_bid_price = float(values["bidPrice"])
        binance_ask_price = float(values["askPrice"])

def compare(): #this part is not working 
    if binance_symbol == w_symbol
        if binance_ask_price < w_ask_price:
            print("buy" + binance_symbol + "on Binance")
        else:
            print("buy" + binance_symbol + "on Wazirx")
            
compare()
```

Comment: ```grab those values``` ? what values?

Comment: what I was trying to say is I can't access the w_bid_price from out of the wazi() function. I tried to add "return" at the end of the wazi() function but this time it gave me only the first value but I got 60 different symbol in the filtered list

Comment: None of those functions have a return statement. So the compare functions is not able to know what the values are, because they are not in the global context

Comment: @IvanCalderon when I add return statement it gave me values for the first coin in my list, but not all of them

Comment: Can you please specify what values you are getting in `coins_list_text_file` in 2nd line, so that it would be helpful to understand better.

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer this is what I am getting when I type print(coin_list_text_file):`['ADA', 'ACM', 'ASR', 'ATM', 'AVAX', 'BAR', 'BTT', 'ATOM', 'EOS', 'HOT', 'JUV', 'LTC', 'USDT', 'PSG', 'DOT', 'XLM', 'TRX', 'COMP', 'XTZ', 'ONT', 'NEO', 'DOGE', 'BCH', 'RVN', 'WAVES', 'GAL', 'SNX', 'XRP', 'ANKR', 'ALGO', 'ZIL', 'THETA', 'SOL', 'MINA', 'GAS', 'VCF', 'GOZ', 'AFC', 'INTER', 'FB', 'CITY', 'TRA', 'DASH', 'VSYS', 'ARPA', 'WOO', 'IRIS', 'BNB', 'ONE', 'XMR', 'IOTX', 'FIL', 'BAND', 'VET', 'ANY', 'OCEAN', 'AKRO', 'PAXG', 'ALICE', 'AUDIO', '1INCH']`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this, try this it will work:

```
import requests
import json

def compare():
  wazi_symbol = list(map(lambda x: "{}{}".format(x, "USDT").lower(), coins_list_text_file))
  response_wazi = requests.get('https://api.wazirx.com/sapi/v1/tickers/24hr')
  wazirx_list = json.loads(response_wazi.content)
  wazi_filtered_list = [d for d in wazirx_list if d["symbol"] in wazi_symbol]


  binance_symbol = list(map(lambda x: "{}{}".format(x, "USDT"), coins_list_text_file))
  binance_response = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr')
  binance_list = json.loads(binance_response.content)
  binance_filtered_list = [d for d in binance_list if d["symbol"] in binance_symbol]


  for wazir_value in wazi_filtered_list:
    for binance_value in binance_filtered_list:
      #print(str(wazir_value["symbol"]).lower()," ",str(binance_value["symbol"]).lower())
      if str(wazir_value["symbol"]).lower() == str(binance_value["symbol"]).lower(): 
        if float(wazir_value["bidPrice"]) < float(binance_value["bidPrice"]):
          print("buy {} on Binance".format(str(binance_value["symbol"])))
        else:
          print("buy {} on wazir".format(str(binance_value["symbol"])))

compare()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is exactly what I am looking for. My question is why my code is didn't work?

Comment: @hascet33 Many reasons were there plus one of the biggest reason is you were comparing USDT with INR therefore, it was not a fare comparison either since 1 USDT = 79.80 INR some rate like this is going, therefore the logic of your code was not right, thus comparing usdt with usdt solved the 1st problem

Comment: @hascet33 2nd Problem as everyone pointed out, you were not returning anything and other functions won't be able to access local variable of other functions,since it was out of scope for the calling function i.e `compare()`

Comment: Thank you! Yes I should have to pay more attention to currencies. However I tried to add return statement at the end of the functions, didn't work either. Could you show me the right way to add return statement?

Comment: @hascet33 I can and that was the first thing which I tried, but since both Crypto Exchanges don't have same order of sending tickers, even returning the value will not be sufficient it will require either sorting at key=symbol level or for loops therefore I reduced the code by comparing in the same function.

Comment: I understand it completely. Thank you for your time and explanation

Comment: @hascet33 Glad to help you.

Comment: You can accept it as an answer if it is the required solution for the above problem.

Comment: It is working so far and solved my problem, also I need to read more about functions and return/yield statements. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not working is that the variables you are trying to compare

```
    if binance_symbol == w_symbol
        if binance_ask_price < w_ask_price:
            print("buy" + binance_symbol + "on Binance")
        else:
            print("buy" + binance_symbol + "on Wazirx")
```

which are `binance_symbol`  and `w_symbol`
are not defined in the scope of the function.

When defining a function, all variables defined inside the function are only available in that context. If you would like to access those variables outside the function you would either have to define them as global variables, which is not as good a solution, or return them and get them outside of that function.

You are doing neither.

You should add return statements at the end of the functions manipulating the variables you are interested in (in your case those will be `wazi` and `binance`) and, get the results and use those when doing the Comparison.